# Python numpy product of integers over some range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Given 2 different NDarrays, `A` and `B`, both of the same shape but arbitrary dimensions, how do I get the `NDarray C`, where `C` is the *product of all integers in the range between A and B (inclusive)*.

By this, I mean that `A` is the start array, and `B` is the end array, and I want the array `C`, where every given element is the product of all integers between the start and stop values for that element.

So, the element `C[i,j,k...z]` is the product of all the integers (inclusive) between `A[i,j,k...z]` and `B[i,j,k,...z]`.

The actual number of dimensions could be anywhere from 3 to N.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation can be expressed in terms of the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).  Scipy has a function, [`scipy.special.poch(z, m)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.poch.html) that computes the rising factorial (also known as the Pochhammer function).

For integer scalars `a` and `b`, you want `a*(a+1)*(a+2)*...*b`.  This can be written using the Pochhammer function as `poch(a, b - a + 1)` (assuming `b` >= `a`).

Here's a scalar example:

```
In [88]: import numpy as np

In [89]: from scipy.special import poch

In [90]: a = 2

In [91]: b = 5
```

Compute the product of the integers from `a` to `b`:

```
In [92]: np.prod(np.arange(a, b+1)) 
Out[92]: 120
```

`poch(a, b - a + 1)` gives the same result:

```
In [93]: poch(a, b - a + 1)
Out[93]: 120.0
```

`poch` is a "ufunc", so it will operate element-wise on arrays:

```
In [94]: a = np.array([[2, 3], [4, 5]])

In [95]: b = np.array([[3, 5], [6, 9]])

In [96]: poch(a, b - a + 1)
Out[96]: 
array([[  6.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+01],
       [  1.20000000e+02,   1.51200000e+04]])
```

`poch` returns floating point values.  For sufficiently large arguments, the result *will not be exact*.  For example, here's the computation with Python's integers (which have arbitrary precision), using `a = 100` and `b = 110`:

```
In [50]: from functools import reduce

In [51]: a = 100

In [52]: b = 110

In [53]: reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, range(a, b+1), 1)
Out[53]: 17018214378110225280000
```

That value exceeds the limits of 64 bit integers, and it cannot be represented exactly using 64 bit floating point.

If you need *exact* results for arbitrary inputs, numpy and scipy won't be much help.

Comment: Should one use `np.prod(np.arange())` version if one cares about exact integer arithmetics? It'd be nice to have an example of applying this to arrays.

Comment: No, because  numpy integers will eventually overflow.  If exact results are required for arbitrary inputs, scipy and numpy are not the right tools to use.

Comment: Ok so is there some way to do it with arbitrary precision using Sympy e.g. q-functions Pochhammer? http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/mpmath/functions/qfunctions.html

Comment: @Warren Weckesser Ok I found a sympy falling factorial function that will work to arbitrary precision: sympy.functions.combinatorial.factorials.FallingFactorial. But it is not a ufunc, so how can I make it work on inputs FallingFactorial(A,B) where A and B are my arrays, instead of the way it works now with expression/integer a and integer b?